# Laravel pagination : add new element

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I try to add a specific element in a paginated list with laravel.

In the URL, there is a parameter to see a specific user in my list (the parameter is the user's id). I get the parameter like this:

```
$openUserId = \Input::get('user', null);
```

After that, I've got a list of users with pagination like this:

```
$users = User::filter($filter)
        ->with('company')
        ->isNot(Role::ADMIN)
        ->whereNotIn('id', [auth()->user()->id])
        ->where('status', 'active')
        ->paginate(10)
        ->appends($request->except('page'));
```

I'd like to create my list of users with the user in the url added in the 10 first results, because sometimes the user required isn't in the 10 first users.

I can't create a collection or something like that because I need to keep functions from the pagination (like nextPageUrl() or hasMorePages()).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get these users with two queries, merge the collections and [create `LengthAwarePaginator` paginator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) using the merged collection:

```
$users = User::with('company')->take(1)->get();

$usersToMerge = User::filter($filter)
    ->with('company')
    ->isNot(Role::ADMIN)
    ->where('id', '!=', auth()-id())
    ->where('status', 'active')
    ->take(9)
    ->get();

$users->merge($usersToMerge);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!

Unfortunately, it's not working better. My user with the id 42 for example isn't selected because the 10 first users are selected before. I tried to invert the two "where" condition, it's not better :/

Comment: I tried, not working neither... My user isn't selected in the 10 first results. :/

Comment: @MarjolaineVé I've done some testing and updated the answer. That's the only way to do that I've found at the moment.